# Install MySQL from Bash Script

Tags: ubuntu, centos, yum, apt, mysql

I'm coding a bash script to automate the process of deploying VPS servers but I'm having some trouble while trying to install MySQL from either `aptitude`/`apt-get` or `yum`, this is what I have so far:

```
if [ "$OS" == 'centos' ]; then
    yum -y install  mysql-server > /dev/null 2>&1
elif [ "$OS" == 'ubuntu' ]; then
    aptitude -y install mysql-server > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

It seems that the script keeps running ad infinitum, I suspect the problem is because the `mysql-server` package seems to bring up a wizard to specify the MySQL root password, but I've no idea how to overcome or fill the password from within the script.

Does anyone know how I can work around this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` environment variable.

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive aptitude -y install mysql-server > /dev/null 2>&1
```

or if you will run more than 1 install you might want to add an export to the top of your script

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
aptitude -y install mysql-server > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can do the same under CentOS?

Comment: @Alix Not really and I don't have access to a CentOS box

Comment: Linode has some great guides on lamp setup for a lot of linux flavors: http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides